# span inside anchor not working, any ideas?

Tags: html, css, button, hyperlink, anchor

I am working a piece of coding here where a span is nested within a link, this works for Chrome but not for FF or IE, any ideas? I have also tried nest link with the span but also not working. I know there are some rules about span within anchor but couldn't figure it out with my current coding.
many thanks

```css
.button {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #ffcc00;
  background-color: #006534;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 9px;
  width: 230px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
  top: -40px;
  left: -255px;
}

.button span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.button span:after {
  content: '»';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.button:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.button:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="button" style="vertical-align: middle;">
    <a href="link"><span>Become a member today</span></a></button>
</div>
```

Comment: What does 'not working' mean? - also, why do you have a button with an anchor inside of it? That seems strange.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.button {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #ffcc00;
  background-color: #006534;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 9px;
  width: 230px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.button span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.button span:after {
  content: '»';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.button:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.button:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="link" class="button"><span>taddaa</span></a>
</div>
```

You can use your button class in anchor tag. So no need to add anchor tag in button

Comment: “Simplicity is the Key to Brilliance” ~ Bruce Lee

Answer (score 0):

```css
a {
  display: inline-block; /* inline by default */
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  background: gray;
  color: white;
}

a span {
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<a class='link' href='http://example.com'>
  <span>Link title?</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tyy button styles

```
.button {
   display: inline-block;
   border-radius: 20px;
   border: 2px solid #ffcc00;
   background-color: #006534;
   color: #FFFFFF;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 16px;
   padding: 9px;
   width: 230px;
   transition: all 0.5s;
   cursor: pointer;
   margin: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> This is better way, Without use of button, and work on all browsers

```css
a {
    background: #000;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: orange;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: all 6000;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

span {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
}

a:hover span {
    left: -5px;
    transition: left 1s;
}

a:hover span:after {
    content: ' »';
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<a href="link"><span>Become a member today</span></a>
```